# On The Fly Validating and Manipulating Dictionary by Django-Rest Serializer (NO MODEL)

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, serialization

I have some data (dict) and I want to validate its data structure at the first and ensure about validation, after that I want to change fields name (CamelCase to snake_case), that's all it!

I had lots of searches and I know about `re_presentation` method (it seems it calls only when using ModelSerializer as a parent class) and also read about `ListSerializer`.

Any helps will be appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

This is the possible way to do this

Assume you have a payload like this

```
{
    'data':{

    },
    'serializer_class': 'user_profile'
}
```

Now you will load the serializer by`serializer_class` token from project path. [Please see this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3673231/how-does-django-convert-string-to-modules)

```
serializer_classes = {
    'user_profile': 'path.to.user_profile.serilizer'
}
```

Once you will load the serilizer as module you can pass the `data` to the serializer and perform validation on data.

After validation you can play further with your validated data.